# boost::program_options: How to specify a command without "--" or "-"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I'm using boost::program_options to implement a command-line utility with this syntax:

```
myutil command [--in file_name] [---out file_name]
```

where 'command' is mandatory, and is one of the following:

```
read | write | find | version | help
```

the thing is that 'command' should not require `--` or `-` and I have not found how to do that with boost::program_options.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command line options which have no name are called **[positional options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2891824)**:

```
po::positional_options_description p;
p.add("command", -1);
po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av).
          options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);
```

Comment: Yes this works.

One important caveat: positional option should be added as a regular option as well:

`po::positional_options_description p;`

`p.add("command", -1);`

`boost::program_options::options_description desc;`

`desc.add_options()("command", "read | write | find | version | help");`

`po::variables_map vm;`

`po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av).options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);`